# Additional pages with SPA

Tags: durandal

I'm creating a SPA app using Durandal and I would like to include a credit card payment facility. The guys that I'm looking at requires you to give return URLs to success, cancel and a view other pages, is that possible?

To me it would be breaking the 'single page' part of SPA, but is it possible? Could I do it all in a window?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, this project is lower priority, will get back to this shortly

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't know Durandal, but you would solve this in an SPA using either "hashbang URIs" or actually re-serving the SPA in your webserver for the requested return URI and adjusting the content using the same technique as hangbash URIs but using `history.pushstate`/`history.popstate` instead, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

A more general article from Google is available here that covers the same principle: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

This "works" because SPAs are SPAs only in that the browser requests a new HTML document from the server once (or in your case, twice), the SPA should still be updating the history and address-bar state of the UA as the user navigates the application, just as though it were a regular multi-page application.

A great example of this is GitHub's source navigator: Try here ( https://github.com/angular/angular.js ) and navigate the repository, observe that the contents of the file-listing change as does the address bar, but your browser doesn't reload the whole page... yet if you copy+paste the (modified) address bar address into a new browser window, you get the same page back.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into doing credit card processing from a SPA and the best option I had found was [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).  They supply a javascript file that looks like it would work,  I never implemented it on my project due to time constraints so I can't confirm that it works but it looked very promising.

Answer (score 0):

IFRAMEs are quite good for this sort of thing. You can use jQuery to hook an event handler to the page load event and this will tell you when the other end has responded. Load the 3rd party page into the IFRAME and serve response pages on the URLs you provide to the service provider. As mentioned by others you can use routes to identify the response pages. The IFRAME will stop the round-tripping from mucking up your application state and in fact it is possible to put script in your response pages that dot-notates its merry way up the DOM and into your app.